# Can we use Google Cloud Messaging and APN for commercial use

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

We wanted to use GCM /APN for commercial application to send push notification, Please point o the links to the terms&Conditions page so that we are in compliance while using these service on our prod servers.

Comment: It's not that hard to find from googling around: https://cloud.google.com/terms/